# How to create a Jar file using centos command line

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am new to java, I have a Centos Virtual Machine installed. I have installed jira server and created a sample plugin as per the [atlassian-sdk-documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-helloworld-plugin-project/).

I have [this repository](https://github.com/yonimoses/jira-rest-customfield). This is a maven java project. I have to somehow convert this repository in to jar file and put it in the jira plugin folder somewhere.

I have searched for how to create a jar file from git maven/java repository in centos command line. But, I got pieces here and there.

How can I achieve it.

Comment: You can probably run `mvn clean install` and it will produce a jar file in your `target` directory. I don't think it's necessary to use the atlassian SDK to produce the jar but I could be wrong.

Comment: You can use `mvn amps:debug -Dproduct=jira` to spin up a local jira instance with the plugin running (and a remote debug server available). Then running `mvn package -DskipTests` in a separate terminal session will recompile the plugin, and jira's quickreload plugin will automatically reload the new jar after a brief period of time.